# Suggest approach for handling multiple lambda invocations

Tags: aws-lambda, slack

**Main Problem:**
Lambda function is not exiting after successful external API call, subsequently triggering multiple external API calls.

I have a lambda function that is listening for slack events when an event takes place the lambda function is invoked. I filter these events using some condition checks, and when the targetted event takes place I make an external API call.

The above all works, however, the external API call is being triggered multiple times per one event (~4 times when it should be 1 if successful).

**Idempotent**
- Often people associate this issue with idempotency, however, given its the external API call within a condition block that is being triggered additional times I do not believe this an issue.

- I can confirm that the condition check is correctly filtering the appropriate events
- I can confirm I am receiving a `statusCode 200` before the subsequent (additional) external API calls
- I have included `context.done()` and redundant `callback()` with no luck

**Looking for some suggested approaches**

- Does anybody have a suggested approach to remedy this issue?
- I have read that some people use DynamoDB to track execution requests but this does not sound like a great approach

I have attached the lambda function below:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const sendMessages = async(event, context, callback) => {
    // test the message for a match
    if (event.type === 'message' && event.bot_id !== undefined) {
        console.log("filter events for specific event");

        let URL = 'https://someurl.com/slack/events';
        let response = await axios.post(URL, {
            events: event,
        });
        console.log("response success :: ", response.status);
        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log("condition met");
            context.done();
            callback(null, 'successful request');
        }
    }
    callback(null, 'successful request');
};

// Lambda handler
exports.server = (data, context, callback) => {
    let eventData = JSON.parse(data.body);
    switch (data.path) {
        case "/slack-events": sendMessages(eventData.event, context, callback); break;
        default: callback(null);
    }
};
```

**Expected behavior**

- Make a single external API call upon invocation and condition check; exit after response.status === 200

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, would you please reach out to the docs team and see if they can update the docs? I reached out to @SebastienStomarq once and he said he had talked to the docs team already, but so far no docs have been updated. Most of the questions we get to answer on SO these days is regarding `async/await` used in conjunction with `context` and `callback` calls, creating an absolute mess. These questions will keep coming if the docs are not fixed.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi You can click the "Feedback" button on documentation pages, which will be routed to the documentation teams. However, if you wish to write-up a more detailed explanation, feel free to email it to me and I will raise it with the documentation team. (I'm not a Node person, so it would be good to have somebody familiar with most problems document the issue for them.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Perfect. I will do so when I have some free time to write up a detailed explanation. Thanks for taking the time to get back to me. Maybe open-sourcing the docs would be a good idea...

Comment: @ThalesMinussi The AWS documentation is available on github, so you can submit pull requests (but I'm not sure that _ALL_ manuals are on there).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/issues/754 I have gone ahead and created a PR already. Let's see how both you folks at AWS and the community react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (you are not the first nor will you be the last one asking this type of question, AWS needs to fix the docs ASAP) is because you are mixing up `async/await` with `context.done` and `callback()` calls.

If your functions already are `async`, then stick with `await` all the way through and forget about `context` and `callback` objects.

See that `sendMessages` is `async`, therefore it returns a Promise, but you don't do anything with that Promise. You should `await` on it. I have changed your code accordingly and got rid of both `context` and `callback` objects, you don't need them.

```
const axios = require('axios');

const sendMessages = async (event) => {
  // test the message for a match
  if (event.type === 'message' && event.bot_id !== undefined) {
    console.log('filter events for specific event');

    let URL = 'https://someurl.com/slack/events';
    let response = await axios.post(URL, {
      events: event,
    });
    console.log('response success :: ', response.status);
    return response;
  }
  return Promise.resolve({});
};

// Lambda handler
exports.server = async (event) => {
  let eventData = JSON.parse(event.body);
  switch (event.path) {
    case '/slack-events':
      await sendMessages(eventData.event);
      break;
  }
  return {
    message: 'Success',
  }
};
```

If this Lambda is invoked by API Gateway, then you need to return a 2xx status code (or 4xx and 5xx in case of errors) with a stringified body so it can terminate properly, like so:

```
return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({message: 'Success'})
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That makes perfect sense and I have refactored the lambda function accordingly, however, the problem persists. Now that I am awaiting on the sendMessages promise correctly, should I do anything with the response to terminate/exit the function in the lambda handler?

Comment: You are more than welcome. Not really...that `return { message: 'Success }` block should be able to handle it. Unless this is a call from API gateway. Is this the case? If so, you need to add the statusCode and stringify the body. I will update my answer.